# Как реализовать передвижение персонажа в Delphi?

Tags: delphi, разработка-игр, delphi-xe

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);    
if (image1.Left < 1000) then
    begin
        if key = vk_right then image1.Left := image1.Left + 5;
        end;
        if (image1.Left > 0) then
           begin
               if key = vk_left then image1.Left := image1.Left - 5;
               end;
    end;
```

Есть другие идеи или же доработка этого кода?

**Обновление**

1. И как заставить его прыгать?

Comment: @Redpower9100, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Что именно не получается? Пока видно просто движение персонажа влево и вправо. В чем проблема сама?

Comment: 1.Когда персонаж т.е image1 доходит до координат 0 или 1000 то он перестает двигаться. 
2. И как заставить его прыгать.

Answer (score 1):

Для прыжка используйте смещение вверх на 10 пикселей и запускаете таймер, который опускает персонажа на 2 пикселя вниз, 5 раз каждые эмм 200-300 мс.